# IIS Routing - Routing to an application just when there is no other route equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, routes

I'm with a problem:

We have the global company site:
www.example.com

And there is pages, etc... a normal website (.aspx)

We are migrating some Customer applications to this server to access them like this:
www.example.com/aplication

but nowadays we have more than 100 applications, and there is a mess on IIS.

What we are trying is:

when there is a request with
www.example.com/something 
And if "something" are not listed on IIS, it calls an .aspx application(like a router) to see if it is an valid application and redirect the request.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into an [IIS Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework) that may be able take care of this.

Another option I'd look into is [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).